# Android update OS

Tags: android

I am building Android apps and have an HTC Desire with running 2.1 of Android.

How do I upgrade, or even downgrade, OS on the phone to test the app on real devices as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install another (older or newer) firmware. In my opinion that doesn't make much sense though - if you want to re-install a firmware over and over again, that's quite time-consuming, only in order to test your app for different versions.

Better to get an (maybe used - then cheaper) G1 phone with 1.6 on it to do tests with an older Android version. That's what I'm doing to test for older devices.

Answer (score 1):

With the SDK, you can select OS from 1.1 to 2.2.

In many cases, that should be enough.

If you really need real hardware, please consider DevPhone1(Google version HTC Dream) or DevPhone2(Google version HTC Magic).

DevPhone1 supports 1.1 to 1.6 by Google. Other guys support 2.0 to 2.2
 DevPhone2 supports 1.5 and 1.6 by Google. Other guys support 2.0 to 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Software Developer seeking to break into Android, so I am not developing yet. Nevetheless, it would seem to me that you ought to listen to the previous advice given to you. However, as a Developer, it seems as though you should be or should have been using the Android 1.6 compiler on your PC and then running the finished application on your Android 2.1 OS. In other words, you have it the wrong way around! Developers know that if you want backwards compatibility, then one should use the oldest development software possible, otherwise, you can run into a whole world of problems!